# Plant identification (I think it could be some kind of lilly?)

Tags: identification, flowering

I saved this plant from a dumpster at a botanical garden last year (around August) and it has just started to bloom as shown in pics. Now I am even more curious as to what species this plant might belong to? I think it could be a lily.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Plant with long thin leaves and a pink flower] | [image: Plant with long thin leaves and a pink flower] |

(in the background a chili plant and some *Pachypodium lamerei*) and with a blurred pothos in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a bromeliad called Queen's Tears (*Billbergia nutans*). I'm impressed that you've gotten it to flower, so keep doing what you've been doing regarding watering and fertilizing. The [World of Succulents site](https://worldofsucculents.com/billbergia-nutans-queens-tears/) has some photos and more cultural information to help confirm my ID.